# calculating width & height relative to container using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, variables, jquery-selectors

My image container is `image-wrap` class , `.image-wrap img` width & height is set to 100% which fill the container.

Css:

```
    .image-wrap{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    .image-wrap img{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
```

Now I want to set 5 px padding inside image-warp, this also need to change `.image-wrap img` width and height to some another `%` value. How to calculate and set this as jquery var, so I can add it to `image-wrap img` class using jquery. My padding of 5 px remains same even for any other width -height value pair for `image-wrap` (may be for responsive design).Help me evaluating mathematical equation to set width height %  as jquery var.

Comment: if you want to stay in % for the image the formula would be 590*100/600. It is then 99.something %.

Comment: I want to set padding of 5 px. so my image width and height is always 10 px less than that height-width of image-wrap container.

Comment: Thanks sven! you have calculated it like this (600px-10px). But I want to calculated it with jquery for any height-width parameter of container.

Comment: then you don't use fixed numbers in the formula, you just query the height/width of the element and subtract 10px from it. Then you have it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(".image-wrap").each(function() {

    myWidth = jQuery(this).width();
    myHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    myWidth = myWidth - 10;
    myHeight = myHeight - 10;
    myWidth = myWidth.toString().concat("px");
    myHeight = myHeight.toString().concat("px");

    jQuery(this).find("img").css({

        height: myHeight,
        width: myWidth
    });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have already got the same. no need to concat("px). we can simply get it by var + "px".

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
   var $imgHeight = $('.image-wrap img').height();
   var $imgWidth = $('.image-wrap img').width();
```

You can do it with css3 too:

```
.image-wrap img{
  position:relative;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: that is not true, you can do it with jquery and without any only partly supported CSS3 property.

Comment: This is just an example that it can be done only with css. What is wrong with it?

Comment: It is wrong that you write you can do it only with CSS3. That gives the impression there is no other possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("img.image-wrap").css({padding:'5px', width:'590px', height:'390px'});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! This is for fixed with height , but I want to set this dynamically for any height width pair.